# C# Outlook distinguish folder by its special type

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, outlook-2010

I need to check if a given folder has a special type. For example, I need to check if a folder is an outbox folder. I know I could retrieve the outbox folder with `Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);`
but that way I could only access the outbox folder of my main mailbox. Since I'm working with multiple mailboxes, that won't be enough.
I know I could difference the folder by checking its name but since the name is localized and it should work in every language, that's not acceptable solution.

Or maybe there is a way to retrieve all folders of a special type like outbox that would bring me a step forward.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
HashSet<string> excludeFolderIds = new HashSet<string>();
Outlook.Stores stores = application.Session.Stores;
foreach(Outlook.Store store in stores){
    //exclude outbox folder from event
    Outlook.MAPIFolder exclude =  store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
    excludeFolderIds.Add(exclude.EntryID);
}
```

and check later if a folder has this type by calling `excludeFolderIds.Contains(folder.EntryID)`

so `store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolder)` is the key to get Default folders from a different account